# Как отследить OSError?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ос

Пишу интерфейс для библиотеки [ImageAI](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) пытаюсь сделать удобно для невнимательных пользователей которые не скачивают модели, а для этого надо отследить OSError который выдается из-за ошибки файла, пытаюсь отследить и через модуль git-clone клонировать модели, OSError не ловится.

---

Код

---

```
import pip
try:
    from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
    from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
    from tkinter import filedialog as fd
    from tkinter import *
    import os
except ModuleNotFoundError:
        def install(package):
            if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
                pip.main(['install', package])
            else:
                pip._internal.main(['install', package])
        install('tensorflow')
        install('https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/2.0.2/imageai-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl')
        install('keras')
        install('h5py')
        install('matplotlib')
        install('pillow')
        install('opencv-python')
        install('numpy')
        install('scipy')
        from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
        from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
        from tkinter import *
        from tkinter import filedialog as fd
        import os


# Main variables
exec_path = os.getcwd()
root = Tk()

def vftrue():
    global vf
    vf = True
    print(vf)

def vffalse():
    global vf
    vf = False
    print(vf)

def start():
    global vf
    ifp = entry_file_path.get()
    ofp = entry_file_path1.get()
    if vf == True:
        print("Starting to render video")
        detector = VideoObjectDetection()
        try:
            detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
            detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(exec_path, "yolo.h5"))
        except:
            git_clone("https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/yolo.h5")
        detector.loadModel()
        list = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(
            input_file_path=os.path.join(exec_path, ifp),
            output_file_path=os.path.join(exec_path, ofp),
            frames_per_second=20
        )
        label = Label(root, text="Succeful!", fg="green")
        label.pack()
    elif vf == False: 
        print("Starting to render photo")
        detector = ObjectDetection()
        try:
            detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
            detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(exec_path, "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
        except OSError:
            git_clone("https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/1.0/resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5")
        detector.loadModel()
        list = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(
            input_image=os.path.join(exec_path, ifp),
            output_image_path=os.path.join(exec_path, ofp),
            display_percentage_probability=True,
            display_object_name=True
        )
        label = Label(root, text="Succeful!", fg="green")
        label.pack()

root.title("Objecter")
root.resizable("False", "False")
root.geometry("200x200")

label1 = Label(root, text="Choose file type")
choose = Button(root, text="Video", command=vftrue)
choose1 = Button(root, text="Photo", command=vffalse)
entry_file_path = Entry(root)
entry_file_path.insert(END, "Input file name") 
entry_file_path1 = Entry(root, text="Output file name")
entry_file_path1.insert(END, "Output file name") 
recognit = Button(root, text="Start", command=start)

label1.pack()
choose.pack()
choose1.pack()
entry_file_path.pack()
entry_file_path1.pack()
recognit.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Код ошибки

---

```
  File "DetectObjects.py", line 72, in start
    detector.loadModel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageai/Detection/__init__.py", line 185, in loadModel
    model.load_weights(self.modelPath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1157, in load_weights
    with h5py.File(filepath, mode='r') as f:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 394, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 170, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '/home/inakoto/asd/Python/guimageai/resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

---

*OS* - **Linux**

---

Comment: Текст ошибки надо вставлять текстом, а не вырвиглазным скриншотом. Если исключение не ловится, значит, ловите не там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключение возникает в `detector.loadModel()`, его и надо окружать блоком `try`.